# visual c++ coin change system for dispensing machines

Tags: arrays, visual-c++, coin-change

recently i've been given an assignment to work on a new project in c++...and i've been doing some thinking for some days and nights on how to approach it....unfortunately the thinking hasn't worked out and currently struggling on the designing phase. Basically the premise is:

*"The management of Ruddles, a well known local department store has decided to implement certain changes to the customer tills throughout the store. Because of problems with staff in providing customers with correct change for their purchases, in future the change will be calculated automatically from the price of the goods and the amount tendered by the customer. The coins will be dispensed automatically by the tills, which are about to be replaced with machines capable of mechanical dispensing."*

this is just some information about the business itself. the following is the requirement specification given to me:

*"As at present, the member of staff (the cashier) will enter the purchases, and the system will calculate the total cost. This part of the system currently operates satisfactorily, and no changes (!) are envisaged. The total cost will be passed to the new machine, and the amount tendered by the customer will also be entered.
The system will then calculate the amount of change due, and will provide the hardware interface with a list of coin denominations and the number of each to be dispensed.
This constitutes the first part of the exercise. However, management has just realised that the coin dispensing machines will need to be replenished with coins from time to time, and would like the system to be able to keep track of the numbers of coins of different denominations, and issue warnings when the number of coins of any given denomination falls below a certain value. You should therefore include facilities to provide such provision in your solution.
At the present time, the hardware is unable to dispense notes, but future developments may make it possible, and your solution should be such as to cope with this should theses improvements occur.  You should therefore indicate what changes would be necessary to the software in the event that such hardware upgrading takes place."*

At the moment im really unsure on how to approach the following requirements for the project so im just wondering if any of you who are far more knowledgeable and experienced than me can lend some advice or suggestions, this will be much appreciated for your time and attention:-)

Im aware that there may be multiple ways this can be approached but so far i understand that arrays need to be used and a persistence structure as well although im not entirely sure..

fortunately it doesn't have to be overly completed so long as it does the job. again i appreciate any advice or tips you can give me. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The described "software" has inputs: the total purchase, and the total tendered by the customer, and outputs: a list of coin denominations and the number of each coin.  Sounds like the definition of a function to me.  Figure out a good data type for each parameter, and write out the signature of your function.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, start simple. Pretend you've only got one coin type, and come up with something that will work for that. Then, extend the design to two coins of different values. After that you'll be getting a far better feel for what is needed, and you should be able to see how to extend your solution to cope with coins that have a number of different denominations.

And also forget about the persistence bit until you've got some of the other basics working.

If you try and design the whole thing in your head without actually implementing any code, your brain might explode. So, break the problem down into chunks you can manage.

It sounds like a fun problem, good luck!